# Anchor tag : Open div on click and change bg color on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.nav_bar {
  background: #c30015;
  margin-left: 50px;
  float: left; }
  .nav_bar ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: thin white solid; }
    .nav_bar ul li {
      list-style: none; }
      .nav_bar ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        display: block;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        padding: 8px 16px; }
  .nav_bar ul li a:hover {
    background: #e6b3a1;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c3000f; }

.down_nav_bar {
  background: #e6b3a1;
  margin-left: 34px;
  float: left; }
  .down_nav_bar ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex; }
    .down_nav_bar ul li {
      list-style: none; }
      .down_nav_bar ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #c3000f;
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 23px 8px 18px; }
  .down_nav_bar ul li a:link {
    text-decoration: none; }
  .down_nav_bar ul li a:visited {
    border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
    text-decoration: none; }
  .down_nav_bar ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
    text-decoration: none; }
  .down_nav_bar ul li a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
    text-decoration: none; }
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar">
                <ul>
                                      <li><a href="#">Post sponsor job</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Applied KOLs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Purchase and billing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>




<div class="down_nav_bar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Purchase Plan</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">My account</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">Invoice</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">How to pay</a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Hello,
My doubt is When I hover on **purchase billing** then second navigation menu  should appear to the down and **purchase billing** should have a the same background on clicking when we hover that **li**.

Just like [image: in this image]

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This snippet displays the down menu on clicking the `purchase and billing` link

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.down_nav_bar').removeClass('displayed');
  $('#purchase').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#purchase').addClass('newColor');
    $('.down_nav_bar').addClass('displayed');
  });
  $('.nav_bar>ul>li:not(#purchase)').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#purchase').removeClass('newColor');
    $('.down_nav_bar').removeClass('displayed');
  });
  $('.nav_bar>ul>li').click(function(){
    $('.nav_bar>ul>li').removeClass("newColor");
    $(this).toggleClass('newColor');
  });
});
```

```css
.nav_bar {
  background: #c30015;
  margin-left: 50px;
  float: left; }
  .nav_bar ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: thin white solid; }
    .nav_bar ul li {
      list-style: none; }
      .nav_bar ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        display: block;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        padding: 8px 16px; }
  .nav_bar ul li a:hover {
    background: #e6b3a1;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c3000f; }

.down_nav_bar {
  background: #e6b3a1;
  margin-left: 34px;
  display:none;
  float: left; }
  .down_nav_bar ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex; }
    .down_nav_bar ul li {
      list-style: none; }
      .down_nav_bar ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #c3000f;
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 23px 8px 18px; }
  .down_nav_bar ul li a:link {
    text-decoration: none; }
  .down_nav_bar ul li a:visited {
    border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
    text-decoration: none; }
  .down_nav_bar ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
    text-decoration: none; }
  .down_nav_bar ul li a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
    text-decoration: none; }
.down_nav_bar.displayed{
  display:block;
}
.newColor{
  background: #e6b3a1;
  color:#c3000f;
}
.nav_bar ul li.newColor>a{
  color:#c3000f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav_bar">
                <ul>
                                      <li><a href="#">Post sponsor job</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Applied KOLs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="purchase"><a href="#">Purchase and billing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>




<div class="down_nav_bar displayed">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Purchase Plan</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">My account</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">Invoice</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">How to pay</a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: can't i do it without using javascript or jquery? as i just want it to appear when i click on 3rd li.. so in that case it would be active state of a tag.

Comment: with `css`, using `:hover` you can change property of that element or it's child elements but you cant change property of other eements.

Comment: it helps me but not perfectly. what is want is.. when i hover on 3rd li then menu gets appear right. and when i click on the 3rd li itself then the background should be same as the hover .. right.. but when i click on others li then menu should get disappear. that's what i wanted.

Comment: yeah.. sure.. no worries.. you can take.. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131501/discussion-between-rishi-and-anuja-agarwal).

Answer (score 0):

simply fix this with css , check it if this is what you need ?

```css
.nav_bar {
background: #c30015;
margin-left: 50px;
float: left;
}
.nav_bar > ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display: flex;
border-bottom: thin white solid;
position:relative;
}
.nav_bar ul li {
list-style: none;
}
.nav_bar ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
display: block;
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
padding: 8px 16px;
}
.nav_bar ul li a:hover {
background: #e6b3a1;
text-decoration: none;
color: #c3000f;
}
.nav_bar ul li a:active , .nav_bar ul li a:focus {
background: #e6b3a1;
text-decoration: none;
color: #c3000f;
}
.nav_bar ul li:hover .down_nav_bar {
display:block;
}
.down_nav_bar {
background: #e6b3a1;
margin-left: 34px;
float: left;
position:absolute !important;
left:0;
width:100%;
display:none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.down_nav_bar li {
list-style: none;
display:inline-block;
}
.down_nav_bar li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #c3000f;
display: block;
padding: 8px 23px 8px 18px;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:link {
text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:visited {
border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:hover {
border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:active {
border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li .active {
border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Post sponsor job</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Applied KOLs</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Purchase and billing</a>
      <ul class="down_nav_bar">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Purchase Plan</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">My account</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">Invoice</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">How to pay</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

yes or you can do it with `:target` property like

```css
.nav_bar {
  background: #c30015;
  margin-left: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.nav_bar > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: thin white solid;
  position:relative;
}
.nav_bar ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
.nav_bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.nav_bar ul li a:hover,
.nav_bar ul li a:focus,
.nav_bar ul li a:active,
#target:target {
  background: #e6b3a1;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c3000f;
}

.down_nav_bar {
  background: #e6b3a1;
  margin-left: 34px;
  float: left;
  position:absolute !important;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  display:none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.down_nav_bar li {
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block;
}
.down_nav_bar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c3000f;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 23px 8px 18px;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:visited {
  border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li a:active {
  border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.down_nav_bar li .active {
  border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#target:target + ul {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Post sponsor job</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Applied KOLs</a> </li>
    <li><a id="target" href="#target">Purchase and billing</a>
      <ul class="down_nav_bar">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Purchase Plan</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">My account</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">Invoice</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">How to pay</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: yes.. but when i remove hover then menu went disappear.

Comment: you want to stay the div when we hover out the menu also right ?

Comment: just one thing sir. when the 3rd li is in active state that is when we click on it then it doesn't get background which was on hover

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131499/discussion-between-jishnu-v-s-and-rishi).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simply with jquery/javascript. Check this out.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav_bar ul li").click(function(){
                     if($(this).text().trim()==='Purchase and billing'){
        $(".down_nav_bar").show();
                $(".nav_bar ul li").css('background-color', '#c30015')
        $(this).css('background-color', '#e6b3a1');
                
      }else{
        $(".down_nav_bar").hide();
  $(".nav_bar ul li").css('background-color', '#c30015');
      }
               
        
});
});
```

```css
.nav_bar {
  background: #c30015;
  margin-left: 50px;
  float: left; }
  .nav_bar ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: thin white solid; }
    .nav_bar ul li {
      list-style: none; }
      .nav_bar ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        display: block;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        padding: 8px 16px; }
  .nav_bar ul li a:hover {
    background: #e6b3a1;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c3000f; }

.down_nav_bar {
  background: #e6b3a1;
  margin-left: 34px;
  float: left; }
  .down_nav_bar ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex; }
    .down_nav_bar ul li {
      list-style: none; }
      .down_nav_bar ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #c3000f;
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 23px 8px 18px; }
  .down_nav_bar ul li a:link {
    text-decoration: none; }
  .down_nav_bar ul li a:visited {
    border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
    text-decoration: none; }
  .down_nav_bar ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
    text-decoration: none; }
  .down_nav_bar ul li a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px #c3000f solid;
    text-decoration: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav_bar">
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Post sponsor job</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Applied KOLs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Purchase and billing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>




<div class="down_nav_bar" style="display:none">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Purchase Plan</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">My account</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">Invoice</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">How to pay</a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: when i click on other li then menu should get disappear. because that menu should come only when i hover it and click on 3rd li.